# Solenoid control with current limiter - is it correct?

Tags: mosfet, schematics, opto-isolator, solenoid, current-limiting

last year, I designed a solenoid control board which is still working very well.
The board was based on ATmega328p and used an optoisolator [6N136](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1304/0900766b813040ba.pdf) to isolate the high power from the low power and I used a [MCP1406](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/137e/0900766b8137e9ac.pdf) as MOSFET driver for the [FQP30N06L](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1538/0900766b8153822d.pdf).

Now, I would like to update my board by adding a **current limiter** in order to set the maximum current to **2A**.

I saw the [Maxim 17525](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1620/0900766b816204eb.pdf) Adjustable Power Limiter and I tried to integrate it in my previous design. I did the connections in this way:

- **SETI**: I connected a 18.7k resistor to SETI output to limit the current to 2A as specified in table 3 at page 18 in the [datasheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1620/0900766b816204eb.pdf).
- **CLTS1** and **CLTS2**: I left unconnected the port CLTS1 and CLTS2 to set the continuous mode as described at page 13
- **OVLO**: I connected a 100k resistor to OVLO port to set the overvoltage to 27V as reported at page 12
- **UVLO**: I connected a 340k resistor to UVLU for undervoltage (9V)
- **OUT**: I connected the output of the device to the drain of the MOSFET.

The solenoid can work at 12VDC/24VDC at 2A.

[image]

I'm a beginner, so I'm pretty sure I did lots of mistakes with the connections.
Can you please give me some advices?
How can I correct the circuit?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested it? What did you find?

Comment: I tested everything without the MAX17525 device and it works very well. I didn't test the circuit with the MAX device since I would like to know if it can work or not, so I can avoid to destroy components :)

Comment: Get a suitable power supply and set the current limit on it so that just enough current flows to move the solenoid. If that seems to work you have ruled out 95% of potential problems without involving a dozen SE users looking up the data sheet and trying to work out if a pin is wrongly numbered. Don't be a baby; give it a go.

Comment: I'm not a baby and I cannot use a power supply by setting a current limit since I will need to change the maximum forwarding current by software in future. It's for this reason that I will replace the resistor on SETI port with a digital potentiometer so I can change the current limiter behaviour. It's also for this reason that I chose the MAX17525 because it ranges from 1A to 6A. What I would like to know is if the circuit I posted contains any mistakes (I'm sure it does).

Comment: IF you have no Thermal design experience nor SMPS design experience, get a DAC control Current limited supply. You may be WAY over your head. They are much cheaper than **years or months of hard work learning**, unless you want to learn the slow way.  There are too many unknowns in this question that are a "tell".  Driving a current regulated 1kW linear servo motor is not trivial with many spurious electro-mechanical resonances.  Been there , done that, early '80's  (Burroughs 207 HDD)  ( fastest 14" HDD Linear motor in the world at the time for given mass and travel length and accuracy)

Comment: Do you know what/how many servo phase margin factors are involved?. What's your bearing resonant frequency and hysteresis? \what's your L/R ratio/?  DCR/RdsOn ratio? position feedback accuracy?  Velocity profile?  2A tells me your motor is too lossy to begin with.  Wrong impedance.  **Toss everything** you have done and retry System level specs 1st. Then return with intelligent specs.  Not a poor implementation with vastly insufficient specs.

Comment: Hello Tony, I'm sorry but I cannot understand your answer. I need to control a small 12vdc solenoid (hydraulics electrovalve). My board already works fine, I just want to add a current limiter. I can't understand why you talked about 1kW servo motor.

Comment: Guessed , based on your previous https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280177/suggestions-on-how-to-control-a-1000w-dc-motor and the fact you wanted uC control. (servo) If different, then still lacking specs.

Comment: It is a different question, i already implemented the servo aspect and it works great. Now, I need to add the current limiter to limit the current drawn by the solenoid. The uC control is not a problem for me. I would like to know only if the circuit I posted contains errors and if it makes sense.

Comment: What specs are missing? I can add them to the question

Comment: Any suggestions about the schematics? Does it contains errors?